# How to display specific row of data based on dropdown menu value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

As the title said, I want to display the specific row of data based on the user selection of the year.

If user selected 2017, I only want to display rows of data that are created in the year of 2017.

I know there are something wrong with my query, I am trying to understand how can I write the query. Can anyone please help me? Thank you in advance!

```
<form action="Report1.php" method="POST">
    Select Year:<select name="sortyear" id="sortyear">
        <option>2017</option>
        <option>2018</option>
    </select>
    <?php
        $sortyear = $_POST['sortyear'];
        $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','customercaremodule');
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
        if ($db->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
        }
        $sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email, message, FC_DateTime FROM fbcomplain WHERE (YEAR(FC_DateTime) = $sortyear)";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Are you asking how to do this without reloading the form?  Do you want an AJAX call to fetch the rows for the Year as soon as the user selects a year from the form?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring security flaws, you could do the following:

```
<?php $getYears = sqlquery() ?>
<form action="Report1.php" method="POST">
<select name="sortyear" id="sortyear">
 <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $getYears.length; $i++): ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $getYears[$i];?>"><?php echo $getYears[$i];?></option>
 <?php endif; ?>
</select>
```

You can do

```
<?php for () {
}?>
```

but the for: allows you to drop back to html code and get your syntax highlighting ;)

Comment: Security isn't my concern for now, This is a school project.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by adding a **button**

```
<input type ="submit" name="search" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Filter" style="background-color: #474747;padding: 5px 5px !important;margin-bottom:5px;">
```

and coded the php this way

```
        if(isset($_POST['search']))
        {

                      $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','customercaremodule');
                      date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
                      if ($db->connect_error) {
                          die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
                      }
            $sortyear = $_POST['sortyear'];
        $sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email, message, FC_DateTime FROM fbcomplain WHERE (YEAR(FC_DateTime) = $sortyear)";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how a button solved this issue. From your question, I thought you wanted to filter out specific items.

Comment: This query is insecure.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<form action="Report1.php" method="POST">
    Select Year:<select name="sortyear" id="sortyear">
        <option>2017</option>
        <option>2018</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Annual Data" />
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $sortyear = $_POST['sortyear'];
            $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','customercaremodule');
            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
            if ($db->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
            }
            $sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email, message, FC_DateTime FROM fbcomplain WHERE (YEAR(FC_DateTime) = " .$sortyear .")";
            $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

Note that this is mostly your code, I just modified it accordingly to this [artcile](https://www.formget.com/php-select-option-and-php-radio-button/). The key point is I added button, which enables user to submit form.